# Remove pairs in a vector sharing the same first element, but keep the pair containing the largest second element

Tags: c++, vector, unique, std-pair

Let's say the elements of the vector of pairs are

```
1, 0
2, 0
1, 2
2, 4
4, 0
5, 0
```

The output should be

```
1, 2
2, 4
4, 0
5, 0
```

In the above example, the pairs {1, 0}, and {1, 2} are replaced by
the pair {1, 2}, since they share the same first element (1), and the largest second element is (2).

I tried to use `set` and make the vector unique based on the first element but this doesn't fulfill my second condition.

Comment: unclear how output follows from input. Why for example `2,0` disappered?

Comment: " But the conditions are the largest second element will be value of second element correspondence to the first element." can you give an example for that? And, do you know an inefficient way to produce the output? If not, start with that

Comment: Please go back a step and describe what you are actually trying to do with this vector of pairs once you get it. Your question as it stands doesn't make sense. Your pairs are unique already.

Comment: I notice that a close vote was added after I made the edits to the question. "Needs details or clarity" no longer applies to this question IMO. In fact, I can't see any reason to close the question unless it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are trying to do this (in which case nisssh's now-deleted answer should have prior recognition). Efficient? Well, depends what you are actually trying to do ultimately. It would have been better to use a map from the start.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<pair<int,int>> input = { { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 4 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 0 } };
// vector<pair<int,int>> input = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 4 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 } };        // check both

   map<int,int> M;
   for ( auto [ p, q ] : input )
   {
      if ( M.count( p ) ) M[p] = max( M[p], q );
      else                M[p] = q;
   }

   vector<pair<int,int>> output( M.begin(), M.end() );
   for ( auto [ p, q ] : output ) cout << p << " " << q << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 4
4 0
5 0
```

**EDIT**
If you want to use "sort and unique" (as in cigien's comment) then this would work. Output order may or may not be acceptable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

using PR = pair<int,int>;

int main()
{
   vector<PR> input = { { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 4 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 0 } };
// vector<PR> input = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 4 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 } };        // check both

   sort( input.begin(), input.end(), greater<PR>() );
   input.erase( unique( input.begin(), input.end(), []( PR a, PR b ){ return a.first == b.first; } ), input.end() );

   for ( auto [ p, q ] : input ) cout << p << " " << q << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
5 0
4 0
2 4
1 2
```

Comment: Creating a new map doesn't seem very efficient. The transformation could be done in place with a `std::sort` and `std::unique`.

Comment: I think both techniques would formally be O(N log(N)) in time.

Comment: But I appended to the post to use std::sort and std::unique as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You might `std::sort` by increasing `first` and decreasing `second`,
then use `std::unique` based on `first`:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
          [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
              return std::tie(lhs.first, rhs.second) < std::tie(rhs.first, lhs.second);
          });
v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(),
                    [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
                        return lhs.first == rhs.first; }),
         v.end());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4YfoY9593).